# Override product controllers?

Tags: magento-1.9

**My Config.xml**

```
<global>
      <admin>
                <routers>
                    <adminhtml>
                        <args>
                            <modules>
                                <product_warranty before="Mage_Adminhtml">product_warranty</product_warranty>
                            </modules>
                        </args>
                    </adminhtml>
                </routers>
            </admin>
</global>
```

My productcontroller.php

```
<?php
 require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/catalog/ProductController.php';
// include_once("Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php");
class Product_Warranty_Catalog_ProductController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController
{

    public function saveAction()
    {


        echo "pankaj"; die;

     }
}
```

Not working..whats wrong with my code.....

Comment: remove `<global>` tag and then try

Comment: also add the `Productcontroller.php` file path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `<global>` tag  and replace

`<product_warranty before="Mage_Adminhtml">product_warranty</product_warranty>`

with

```
 <Product_Warranty before="Mage_Adminhtml">Product_Warranty</Product_Warranty>
```